# Show different message to the hours | php

Tags: php, time, message, zone

here is  my code, where i make mistake? Btw my time ZONE is UTC + 2:00.
Thanks for answers in advance.

```
<?php

    $current_time = date('H');

    if ($current_time >18) {
    echo "Good night";
    }
    if ($current_time <12) {
    echo "Good morning";
    }
    if (($current_time >=12) && ($current_time <17)) {
    echo "Good day";
    }

?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What doesn't work? WHat does `$current_time` contain?

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_time = date('H');

if ($current_time >18) {
echo "Good night";
} else if ($current_time <12) {
echo "Good morning";
} else {
echo "Good day";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last test should check for `$current_time <=17`. Note the less than or equal to...
`if (($current_time >=12) && ($current_time <=17))`

@Ernestas Stankevičius has a [nice clean solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548765/show-different-message-to-the-hours-php/7548788#7548788) though.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `var_dump($current_time);`. That way, you will understand what it contains and where you are making a mistake.

Comment: and use a if-else ladder to reduce no. of comparison checks

Answer (score 0):

As predicted, the problem is in time zone.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');
    $current_time =date('H');

    echo "$current_time";
    if ($current_time >'18') {
    echo "Good night";
    }
    if ($current_time <'12') {
    echo "Good morning";
    }
    if (($current_time >='12') && ($current_time <='17')) {
    echo "Good day";
    }

?>
```